# Import and use C++ DLL functions in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I am developing an application that communicates with some hardware using the C++ DLL provided by the hardware provider. I also have a header file for this DLL, but no source file. In my C# application, I'm trying to import and call the DLL's functions like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("CaGe.dll")]
    public static extern long someLibraryFunction();

    public void callLibFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("function call: " + someLibraryFunction());
    }
}
```

The library.dll file is located in the same folder as the MyClass.cs file and also the rest of the project files. When I start the debugging session however, I first receive a dialog window from system saying: CAGE InitDll: Erro on load library "CdbClientInit" and after I click OK on that, an unhalted exception on the line where I call the library function occours.

The exception says: System.DllNotFoundException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A

I found on the internet that this may be caused by a missing DLL that the CaGe.dll needs, so I tried to put the DLL through the Dependency Walker, but the results are a little bit confusing for me. Under the CAGE.DLL there are WS32_32.DLL, VERSION.DLL, KERNEL.DLL and USER32.DLL tabs, I susspect that the libraries I need are somwhere under the USER32.DLL tab, but I don't recognize any of them (if a missing DLL is what is causing this problem).

Any advice would be much appretiated :)

Comment: The problem may be more likely that your program can't find `CaGe.dll`. You said it's in the same directory as your source files, but that's not where your executable gets built (by default.) Try placing the .dll into Bin\Debug or Bin\Release, where your program executable is.

Answer (score -2):

More help to use C++ function in C# please check below URL

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/107152/Using-a-C-dll-in-a-C-application

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Providing a link to an off site resource and nothing more adds nothing to Stack Overflow. Please don't do that. Please take the time to include the essence here. If you want to include links for further reading, that's good too.